# How to change NSSlider tickmarks color?

Tags: macos, nsslider

I know should change the function `drawTickMarks`,but what should I do to change `tickmarks` color?

Comment: What have you tried so far. Show your code.

Comment: I have subclass a NSSliderCell and override `- (void)drawBarInside:(NSRect)rect flipped:(BOOL)flipped`，and `drawTickMasks` is empty.

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9qR9.png)

Comment: Do you mean `drawTickMarks`?

Comment: yes, I don't konw what I should write in `-(void)drawTickMarks`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them in different color, draw them in a different color.

Having an empty implementation of `drawTickMarks()` draws nothing.

[image]

Subclass `NSSliderCell` and set the cell class.

Then provide a drawing routine in `drawTickMarks()`

```
class CustomSliderCell: NSSliderCell {

    override func drawTickMarks() {

        guard let slider = controlView as? NSSlider, slider.numberOfTickMarks > 0 else {
            return
        }

        let tickWidth: CGFloat = 5
        let horizontalinset: CGFloat = 5
        let verticalinset: CGFloat = 1
        let drawRect = slider.bounds.insetBy(dx: horizontalinset, dy: verticalinset) //squish in slightly
        let step = drawRect.width/CGFloat(numberOfTickMarks-1) //classic fenceposts problem
        var mark = CGFloat(0)
        for _ in 0..<numberOfTickMarks {
            let blob = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: NSRect(x: mark + horizontalinset , y:verticalinset, width: tickWidth, height: tickWidth*2), xRadius: tickWidth/2.0, yRadius: tickWidth/2.0)
            NSColor.green.set()
            blob.fill()
            NSColor.darkGray.set()
            blob.stroke()
            mark += step
        }
    }

}
```

This one is a demo and far from perfect but should give you an ideas of what is needed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I need